# Why aren't the values from my arrays passing though my full bit adder

Tags: python-3.x

```
# 8-bit-binary adder

#if you have questions about the code just ask


# arrays and funtions
Array1 = []
Array2 = []
#Input A and Validation
def vaildNumberA():
        a = int(input("Enter your A value:"))
        if (a < 0):
                print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input A")
        elif (a > 255):
            print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input A")
        else:
             Array1 = [int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(a))]
#Input B and Validation
def vaildNumberB():
            b = int(input("Enter your B value:"))
            if (b < 0):
                print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input B")
            elif (b > 255):
                print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input B")
            else:
                Array2 = [int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(b))]


# and gate

# AND Gate
def AND (a,b):
    if (a == 1 and b == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


# or gate


#OR Gate
def OR(a,b):
    if (a == 1 or b == 1):
       return 1
    else:
        return 0

# XOR GATEE


#XOR Gate   
def XOR (a,b):
    if (a == b):
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1

#carry formula
def carryformula(a,b,c,d):
    return OR(AND(a,b), AND(c,d))

# this is where the calculation should be done

#formula for sum
def calculateSum(Array1,Array2): 
    carry = ""
    sumof = []
    for index, in range(len(Array1)):
        list2 = Array2[index]
        sec_xor_form = XOR(Array1[index],Array2[index])
        sumof.append(XOR(sec_xor_form,carry))
        carry = carryformula(Array1[index],Array2[index],sec_xor_form,carry)  
    return list(reversed(sumof))
calculateSum(Array1,Array2)

def main(Array1,Array2):
    vaildNumberA()
    vaildNumberB()
    while True:
        a = Array1
        b = Array2
        total = calculateSum(list(reversed(Array1)),list(reversed(Array2)))
        print(total)
        quit = input("if want to quit type q: ")

        if quit == 'q':
            break
main(Array1,Array2)
```

> in the send it prints 0

Comment: Please add your code in one full block, and add comments to it, instead of breaking it into pieces @KevinMedjiako

Comment: I have tried to edit it but it won't let me can I sent to you another way?

Comment: It should. Just press `edit` on the question, update the code and save it

Comment: it's not allowing me to. here is the full code
https://www.diffchecker.com/qBqHfk7T

Comment: Does it look okay now @KevinMedjiako, also what problem are you facing, can you explain in detail?

Comment: yes it looks better now. so this code is meant to take the 2 user inputs then convert them into a base 2 int and place it this into 2 lists. once it does this it is meant to add these 2 numbers together in by passing them through the bit adder. however atm when I do this I get nothing as an output and i cannot see why that is

Comment: You just forgot to `return` the value of the array from the function, check my answer below @KevinMedjiako

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem in your code is that you need to return `Array1` and `Array2` from your functions and assign them inside the while true loop, once you do that the code works fine.

The updated code will be

```
# 8-bit-binary adder

#if you have questions about the code just ask


# arrays and funtions
Array1 = []
Array2 = []
#Input A and Validation
def vaildNumberA():
    Array1 = []
    a = int(input("Enter your A value:"))
    if (a < 0):
            print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input A")
    elif (a > 255):
        print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input A")
    else:
         Array1 = [int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(a))]

    #Return the array 
    return Array1

#Input B and Validation
def vaildNumberB():

    Array2 = [] 
    b = int(input("Enter your B value:"))
    if (b < 0):
        print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input B")
    elif (b > 255):
        print("Please Enter A Valid Number For Input B")
    else:
        Array2 = [int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(b))]

    #Return the array
    return Array2

# AND Gate
def AND (a,b):
    if (a == 1 and b == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
#OR Gate
def OR(a,b):
    if (a == 1 or b == 1):
       return 1
    else:
        return 0

#XOR Gate   
def XOR (a,b):
    if (a == b):
        return 0
    else: 
        return 1

#carry formula
def carryformula(a,b,c,d):
    return OR(AND(a,b), AND(c,d))

# this is where the calculation should be done

#formula for sum
def calculateSum(Array1,Array2): 
    carry = ""
    sumof = []
    for index in range(len(Array1)):
        list2 = Array2[index]
        sec_xor_form = XOR(Array1[index],Array2[index])
        sumof.append(XOR(sec_xor_form,carry))
        carry = carryformula(Array1[index],Array2[index],sec_xor_form,carry)  
    return list(reversed(sumof))

#No need of a main function
while True:

    #Call the function from within the while True loop 
    Array1 = vaildNumberA()
    Array2 = vaildNumberB()
    total = calculateSum(list(reversed(Array1)),list(reversed(Array2)))
    print(total)
    quit = input("if want to quit type q: ")

    if quit == 'q':
        break
```

And the output will look like

```
Enter your A value:5
Enter your B value:5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
if want to quit type q: 7
Enter your A value:9
Enter your B value:8
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
....
```

Comment: I have noticed an error in the code and you input numbers like 2 and 2 it gives you
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]  but it should give [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0].

Comment: this also happens when you input 2 even numbers

Comment: Hi @KevinMedjiako then that must be some problem in the logic. I addressed what was asked in the question, and that was why the arrays weren't showing up which I addressed. Anything else in the logic might be out of scope for this question, and warrants a new question, where more people can look at your code and see what's going on!